# Inconsistencies Rounding Up with Ceiling Function

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

I have to round a data frame to two decimal places and the 1/100s decimal always needs to round up. However I am seeing some odd behavior with the ceiling function that I'm using.

```
a <- c(268.600, 268.700, 268.500)
b <- c(22.410, 653.423, 124.400)

df1 <- data.frame(a, b)

ceiling(df1 * 100)/100

       a      b
1 268.61  22.41
2 268.70 653.43
3 268.50 124.40
```

I expect the output at df1[1,1] to be 268.60 .. but I am getting 268.61. I am not sure why this is happening; the other numerics in 'a' give the expected output. I'm using R version 3.5.3

EDIT:

@Akrun identified the issue in col A as a result of floating point numbers.

What I am looking for help with now is a way to round a number like 10.032 to 10.04 while also avoiding having a number like 10.000 round to 10.01 due to floating point issues.

Right now I am stuck with either having df1[1,1] round correctly or df[2,2] round correctly but not both.

Comment: The reason is that it a floating point number and not exactly integer `(df1$a * 100) == 26860#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE`. or to find the difference `(df1$a * 100)- 26860
[1]  3.637979e-12  1.000000e+01 -1.000000e+01#`

Answer (score 3):

It is not exactly an integer, so it is not. equal to `26860`

```
(df1$a * 100)- 26860
#[1]  3.637979e-12  1.000000e+01 -1.000000e+01
```

which gets `round`ed with `ceiling`

To avoid that, we can convert to `integer`

```
ceiling(as.integer(df1$a * 100))/100
#[1] 268.6 268.7 268.5
```

Comment: This solves the issue with floating point numbers in col a, however it then removes the functionality I need that impacts col b.

For example, I'd need 10.032 to round up to 10.04 but using as.integer() in the middle of the process removes the decimal I am trying to round up:

e <- 10.032
f <- e * 100
g <- as.integer(f)
h <- ceiling(g)
i <- h/100

I think what I need is to find something that works like the ms Decimal type :(

Comment: @JakeMercer. sorry, that was not your original question

Comment: @JakeMercer. Your question is not clear now.  if you can either post as a new question (if it is totally different) or update the post (if it is similar).  I spend some time on this

Comment: thank you for your help. I have tried to clarify the question.

Comment: @JakeMercer. I can't reproduce the issue.  Can you provide an example `v1 <- c(10.032, 10.000, 10.0001);  ceiling((v1 *100))#
[1] 1004 1000 1001`